# Unable to obtain working Selenium Manager binary

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, seleniummanager

When running the most basic selenium script it causes the error -

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain working Selenium Manager binary; C:\Users\User\.conda\envs\InstaScraper\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\windows\selenium-manager.exe
```

I can see both selenium and selenium-manager are installed with `conda list` with version 4.16.0

When I checked that file path provided, there is no windows folder.

Script run:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/web/web-form.html")
```